# The property 'BookId' on entity type 'Library' has a temporary value. Either set a permanent value explicitly or ensure that the database is

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

When I use Entity Framework Core and seed data with migration, I have this error:

> The property 'BookId' on entity type 'Library' has a temporary
>   value. Either set a permanent value explicitly or ensure that the
>   database is configured to generate values for this property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The message means that you have given a value for your key that did not exist if you have dependencies with ForeignKey.

Comment: This can also mean you have a duplicate foreignkey set up in your Context

Comment: When using PostgreSQL, this error can also occur if there's a sequence bound to the table and the user does not have enough permission to run it.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same exception when I had unique index, AddRange failed on unique index and then inside catch exception block was try to remove whole inserted collection.
(Not my code, but I had to fix it :-) )

Code sample (simplified):

```
try {
    context.AddRange(users); // List<User>, has property List<Contact>
    context.SaveChanges(); // throws exception on unique index
} catch (Exception ex) {
    context.RemoveRange(users); // this throws exception "The property 'UserID' on entity type 'Contact' has a temporary value"
    throw;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message can mislead and create confusion, first I thought it was from the database setup.

I encountered this error when (by mistake) added twice the same object to a list, updated context range with added/modified values and saved back to database:

For example:

```
list = _context.SomeList.ToList();

var obj = new Obj();
list.Add(obj);
 .......
list.Add(obj); //<- second add of the same object
 .......
_context.UpdateRange(list);
_context.SaveChanges(); //<- error
```