# Entity Framework Core - error on SaveChanges

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, database, entity-framework-core

I get this exception when i try to save a list of elements in database, but what interesting is that the data is saved:

> The property 'xxxxx' has a temporary value while attempting to change the entity's state to 'Unchanged'. Either set a permanent value explicitly, or ensure that the database is configured to generate values for this property.

```
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.InternalEntityEntry.SetEntityState(EntityState oldState, EntityState newState, Boolean acceptChanges, Boolean modifyProperties)    
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.InternalEntityEntry.SetEntityState(EntityState entityState, Boolean acceptChanges, Boolean modifyProperties, Nullable`1 forceStateWhenUnknownKey, Nullable`1 fallbackState)    
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.InternalEntityEntry.AcceptChanges()    
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.AcceptAllChanges(IReadOnlyList`1 changedEntries)     
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChanges(StateManager stateManager, Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess) at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.<>c.b__107_0(DbContext _, ValueTuple`2 t)    
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.ExecutionStrategy.<>c__DisplayClass28_0`2.b__0(DbContext context, TState state)    
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.ExecutionStrategy.ExecuteImplementation[TState,TResult](Func`3 operation, Func`3 verifySucceeded, TState state)     
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.ExecutionStrategy.Execute[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`3 operation, Func`3 verifySucceeded)    
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChanges(Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess)     
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SaveChanges(Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess)     
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SaveChanges().
```

Does somebody have a problem like this?

When I try to save this list element by element it goes perfectly, but it's very slow.

Comment: So this is the problem, how about sharing the code part that gives the issue? Provide the model and an example of what you are trying to save to the database.

Comment: Add the code that is causing the error to the question

Comment: `I get this exception when i try to save a list of elements in database` it would be great if you could include that line where you are getting above exception message.

Comment: Might be related to this question here....
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54752158/the-property-bookid-on-entity-type-library-has-a-temporary-value-either-set